# Minecraft 1.13 how to detect players at a certain Y coordinate?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've seen a lot of tutorials for detecting the player at certain X,Y,Z coordinates, but I want to detect only the player's Y coordinate. In this situation I want to detect the player at Y level 18. I tried things like `execute if entity @a[y=18.5,distance=1.5]` but that doesn't work. `execute if entity @a[x=~,y=18.5,z=~,distance=1.5]` doesn't work either. Do I need different commands?

Comment: ⬆️ Just leave out the `execute` part from that answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify x and z, so you want something like

```
execute if entity @a[y=18] run yourcommand
```

Or if you want to detect players between 18 and 19, use

```
execute if entity @a[y=18..19] run yourcommand
```

Comment: I get the following error when trying to use the second command: `Invalid double '18.19'`

Comment: @haykam Probably a typo, you need 2 dots between the numbers 18 and 19. You have only 1 dot.